# Programa ingresar cantidad de productos

Tags: python

Me podrían ayudar quiero que mi código a la hora de sacar el resultado de la cantidad de productos ingresados con sus respectivos valor me den la cantidad que es ya que a mi me sale mal si pongo 3 productos y 2 productos tendrían que darme el valor sin son a $5 cada uno un total de 25 pero me arroja otro ayuda por favor

```
producto_1= int(input("Ingrese cantidad de producto 1 : "))
producto_2= int(input("Ingrese cantidad de producto 2 : "))

precio_unitario1 = float(input("Ingresar precio unitario del primer  producto : $"))
precio_unitario2 = float(input("Ingresar precio unitario del segundo producto : $"))

total_a_pagar=(precio_unitario1+precio_unitario2)*producto_1*producto_2/2
def iva(total):
 descuento=total*0.12
 return total+descuento 

Iva_total_a_pagar=iva(total_a_pagar)
print("____")
print("total a pagar es", total_a_pagar)
print("Aplicado el iva:", Iva_total_a_pagar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se debería multiplicar la cantidad de productos por su valor unitario para después aplicarle la sumatoria.

Ejemplo:

```
total_a_pagar=producto_1*precio_unitario1+producto_2*precio_unitario2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ❤️

Comment: un gusto aportar!.